# vba sql left join syntax error

Tags: sql, excel, left-join, vba

I have this query:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM " & tabla & " LEFT JOIN szlaszamok " & _
          "ON tabla.[Főkönyvi szám]=szlaszamok.[Főkönyvi szám] WHERE [Költséghely]=" & smktghely
```

`tabla` and `szlaszamok` are named ranges.

Excel says, there is a join syntax error. I can't figure out, what is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the var `tabla` then you must use the same var in on clause

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM " & tabla & " LEFT JOIN szlaszamok " & _
          " ON  " & tabla.[Főkönyvi szám] & "=szlaszamok.[Főkönyvi szám] 
            WHERE [Költséghely]=" & smktghely
```

or as suggested

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM " & tabla & " LEFT JOIN szlaszamok " & _
          " ON " & tabla & ".[Főkönyvi szám]=szlaszamok.[Főkönyvi szám] 
            WHERE [Költséghely]=" & smktghely
```

Comment: Did you mean `" ON  " & tabla & ".[Főkönyvi szám]=szlaszamok.[Főkönyvi szám] `

Comment: @RobinMackenzie   .. may be  ... answer  updated  with your suggest ..  many thank

Comment: I was blind. Thank you for your support.